# privilege to vote up a comment

Tags: feature-request

I can vote up a post but am still unable to vote up a comment - ie. the small print below a response. Do i have to earn an additional privilege (which requires grater amount of points)? Thanks ☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

You can always comment on your own posts. At 50 reputation, you gain the privilege to comment on others' posts.

**Edit:**

According to the privileges list, comment votes should be awarded at 15 reputation along with other upvote privileges. However, it is possible that this text is in error and the privilege is actually awarded with "Comment Everywhere" at 50 reputation. Please let us know if you find that ability granted when you reach 50!

Comment: Thanks. (can i say "thank you"s in this meta forum as i am not allowed to do so in the music forum).

Comment: Unfortunately i still can't vote up a comment below my response in my own question page...

Comment: Oh whoops, I actually misunderstood your question.

Comment: No problem, i did get an important piece of information from your response (which is about the privilege points) .. though i am still waiting for a response on my main question.

Comment: Sure, will do. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes i finally got that privilege. There was an unfortunate incident though when one of the moderators (oor senior member) insisted that i had to post my statement as comments while I was not allowed to do so yet! http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6663/what-are-some-interesting-ways-notes-and-chords-are-spelled-in-cultures-outside/29087#29087 (This came across to me as if i wasn't allowed to contribute as much as i would have liked.